# parse_str with comma separed into a key array

Tags: php

I need to convert this string:

```
{"access_token":"EAAV3DehWC2QBAOA6eZCFSgLzlQdtcEvCi57QPJhtseyTMo4raKUvhNS4IRQ0KKat7eNFQlcD9aY212ZC9OlEUoEvBpZAHOlxh6ZBT6VZATVx3K4kKxWMDUTRR3xEHazCkvFeSN3sJXsyGdrjXNpZCJOpFpWI5tzNgxomqJo0xSb3btNvFeRgOrWGmVdE59TtsZD","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":6574}
```

into a array with keys.

This code used to work:

```
parse_str($token_response, $signed_request);

if (isset($signed_request['access_token'])) {
    return $signed_request['access_token'];
}
```

But now the $signed_request['access_token'] is not set.

Comment: Read [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php\])

Comment: @Saty post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @saty Thank you!Post it as an answer so I can accept it :)